# VBA: Extract Top 'x' Entries from each category

Tags: vba, excel

By way of simplified example, say you have the following dataset:

```
 A      B     C
Name  Group Amount
Dave    A     2
Mike    B     3
Adam    C     4
Charlie A     2
Edward  B     5
Fiona   B     5
Georgie A     4
Harry   C     1
Mary    A     0
Delia   A     0
Victor  B     1
Dennis  B     0
Erica   A     4
Will    B     4
```

I'm trying to extract the highest 'x' entries (let's say 2 in this example) from each group.

For example, the highest two entries in Group A are Georgie and Erica with 4. I also then want the highest two entries for Group B and C.

I want the VBA code to extract these rows and paste them on another worksheet for subsequent analysis.

I have tried code like this so far:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
    ("C1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$15").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="A"
Range("A5:C6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$15").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="B"
Range("A2:C3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("E2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$15").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="C"
Range("A4:C11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("I2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

In short, I'm just sorting the values from Largest to Smallest, and then filtering for each group, and extracting the top two values. The code is not resilient, however, as the copy part depends on the names being in a particular order, which will change when I get new data.

Is there a cleverer, cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: You can set dynamic range for copying. Look up how to find last row. Edit: clever may be using some combination of index/match/max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this have to be VBA? It can be done with formulas.

Based on your provided sample data, you could setup Sheet2 like this:

[image: tigeravatar example for Will T-E]

In cell A4 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IF($C4="","",INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$15,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$15=$B4)*(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$15=$C4)*(COUNTIFS($A$3:$A3,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$15,$B$3:$B3,$B4)=0),),0)))
```

In cell B4 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IF(($B$1>0)*COUNT($B$1),IF(OR($B3="Group",COUNTIF($B$3:$B3,$B3)=$B$1),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$15,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($B$3:$B3,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$15),),0)),""),$B3),"")
```

In cell C4 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IF(OR($B4="",COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$15,$B4)<COUNTIF($B$4:$B4,$B4)),"",LARGE(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$15*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$15=$B4),),COUNTIF($B$4:$B4,$B4)))
```

Note that you can copy those formulas down quite a ways, and it will only show desired results.  Extra rows will simply be blank.  You can also change the number in cell B1 to be whatever the number of top entries to be, so you could see top 5 per category, or top 3, etc.

However, if it absolutely must be VBA, then something like this should work for you.  It's not simple, but it is very efficient and flexible.  All you would need to do is update `lNumTopEntries`, your sheetnames, and where your data is located for the `Set rngData` line:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim rngUnqGroups As Range
    Dim GroupCell As Range
    Dim lCalc As XlCalculation
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim aOriginal As Variant
    Dim lNumTopEntries As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    'Change to grab the top X number of entries per category'
    lNumTopEntries = 2

    Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")    'This is where your data is'
    Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")    'This is where you want to output it'

    Set rngData = wsData.Range("A1", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    aOriginal = rngData.Value   'Store original values so you can set them back later'

    'Turn off calculation, events, and screenupdating'
    'This allows code to run faster and prevents "screen flickering"'
    With Application
        lCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'If there are any problems with the code, make sure the calculation, events, and screenupdating get turned back on'
    On Error GoTo CleanExit

    With rngData
        .Sort .Resize(, 1).Offset(, 1), xlAscending, .Resize(, 1).Offset(, 2), , xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    End With

    With rngData.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 1)
        .AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, , , True
        Set rngUnqGroups = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Parent.ShowAllData 'Remove the filter

        ReDim aResults(1 To rngUnqGroups.Cells.Count * lNumTopEntries, 1 To 3)
        i = 0

        For Each GroupCell In rngUnqGroups
            Set rngFound = .Find(GroupCell.Value, .Cells(.Cells.Count))
            k = 0
            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                For j = i + 1 To i + lNumTopEntries
                    If rngFound.Offset(j - i - 1).Value = GroupCell.Value Then
                        k = k + 1
                        aResults(j, 1) = rngFound.Offset(j - i - 1, -1).Value
                        aResults(j, 2) = rngFound.Offset(j - i - 1).Value
                        aResults(j, 3) = rngFound.Offset(j - i - 1, 1).Value
                    End If
                Next j
                i = i + k
            End If
        Next GroupCell
    End With

    'Output results'
    wsDest.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(aResults, 1), UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults

CleanExit:
    'Turn calculation, events, and screenupdating back on'
    With Application
        .Calculation = lCalc
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'There was an error, show the error'
        MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error: " & Err.Number
        Err.Clear
    End If

    'Put data back the way it was
    rngData.Value = aOriginal

End Sub
```

Comment: I hadn't considered it was possible without VBA, and your Excel code absolutely works. I am trying to dissect and understand it, however, so I can apply and adjust it to my real problem. I do not understand how code like like this works `=MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($B$3:$B3,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$15),),0)` - particularly, how does an Index function work without a row number? I have googled it without luck. Many many thanks for your incredible response.

Comment: The VBA works great too, I am going to try and dissect that as well.

Comment: Index without a row number returns an array of values.  In that particular case, it returns an array of countif results with each argument being the count of values in `$B$3:$B3` (that range will extend as the formula is copied down) and it is looking for all items from `Sheet1!$B$2:$B$15`, and then the Match is looking at that countif array and specifically matching 0's.  It is a way of ensuring only unique values get placed in the list to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Sub TopValues()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set StartCell = Range("A1")

Set SrcRange = StartCell.CurrentRegion
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Data"
For i = 1 To 3
    SrcRange.Sort Key1:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(0, i - 1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    sht.Rows("2:3").EntireRow.Copy
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & 2 * i).PasteSpecial
Next i


End Sub
```

The `Rows("2:3")` and `Range("A" & 2 * i)` reflect your x value, which you said was 2 in this example. So the vba copies rows `2:3` and pastes them in row `2*i` in the new sheet.