# Top/Bottom 10 Entries from Each Group/Category Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

anybody knows how to find top/bottom 10 entries from each category? I found a partial solution for my problem from this [StackExchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516441/vba-extract-top-x-entries-from-each-category) , and it works great, except that it only shows the TOP values, not the BOTTOM values.

Anyone can tell me how to do the same for bottom values? I know it requires me to change some of the syntax, but I tried for hours but didn't find any. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried two pivots side by side, one filtered on top 10 & second to bottom 10?

Comment: You can use large() and small() or just one with the correct numbers.

Comment: @ygaft, what I want is top/bottom from each group, not the whole data.

Comment: @SolarMike, I tried changing the Large to Small in the code provided, but it didn't work

Comment: You need to provide a complete and relevant sample of your data - not just rely on some other person’s code...

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in excel's table try the following:

1. Create a Rank Column which will rank each value through your category

   =COUNTIFS([Category],[@Category],[value],">"&[@value])+1
2. Create another column which calculates max value for the category, it is an array formula so, hit ctrl+shift+enter to execute it:

   =MAX(IF([Category]=[@Category],[RANK]))
3. Create  third column to decide top and bottom values based on previous 2 columns, in my example the column is either 1 or 0 to indicate relevant rows:

   =IF([Category]=[@Category],IF(OR([@RANK]<=10,[@RANK]>=[@Мах]-10),1,0))

You'll end up with something like that:
[image]

Hope that helped

Comment: Hi @ygaft, thanks for answering! But the problem is my data is dynamic and come from a power pivot table based on many data files as resources. So I can't use arrays for that. Can you check the link I provided in my question and see what you can change to make it showing bottom values instead? Because the top values search work fine. Thanks so much again.

Comment: Hi @user71812 , basicaly same logic can be applied to the data in powerpivot, I can't see a link :/. you can pm me or edit your question providing more detail. It is necessary to understand your "PP" model...

Comment: here's the link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516441/vba-extract-top-x-entries-from-each-category

Comment: thanks so much for replying again, I provided the link in the comment above. The question is exactly what I wanted (answer by tigeravatar), except I cant figure out the solution for bottom values. Thanks!

Comment: try to change this line xlDescending and xlAscending like that:
    With rngData
        .Sort .Resize(, 1).Offset(, 1), xlDescending, .Resize(, 1).Offset(, 2), , xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End With

Comment: thanks for your help! Although I still need to make some additional changes here and there, I think I get them going in the right direction with your help. Thanks again!