# Select the highest/lowest n values from a sorted column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with 12 columns (A:J) with the 11th column containing the user score and the 12th column containing the user rank. I have created a separate sub to sort the data as necessary. I am attempting to create a new sub to run after the sorting sub that would select the highest and lowest n (e.g. 3) values and then paste the associated rows in a separate sheet in the same workbook.

A sample of the dataset can be seen here:

[image: dataset]

I'm a newbie in VBA and programming. Any help would be appreciated.
Similar questions have been answered here before, but the associated code and explanations do not guide me to the desired results.

Edit:

> In case of multiple users achieving the same score, I would like to select all users with the top/bottom n scores.

The original code was posted by @tigeravatar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34517990/12798804).

Adding the code as mentioned by several kind users in the comments below:

```
Extract Top 'x' Entries from each category

Sub Top 3 values()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim rngUnqGroups As Range
    Dim GroupCell As Range
    Dim lCalc As XlCalculation
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim aOriginal As Variant
    Dim lNumTopEntries As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    'Change to grab the top X number of entries per category'
    lNumTopEntries = 3

    Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")    'This is where your data is'
    Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("National")    'This is where you want to output it'

    Set rngData = wsData.Range("A1", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A:M").End(xlUp))
    aOriginal = rngData.Value   'Store original values so you can set them back later'

    'Turn off calculation, events, and screenupdating'
    'This allows code to run faster and prevents "screen flickering"'
    With Application
        lCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'If there are any problems with the code, make sure the calculation, events, and screenupdating get turned back on'
    On Error GoTo CleanExit

    With rngData
        .Sort .Resize(, 1).Offset(, 1), xlAscending, .Resize(, 1).Offset(, 2), , xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    End With

    With rngData.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 1)
        .AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, , , True
        Set rngUnqGroups = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Parent.ShowAllData 'Remove the filter

        ReDim aResults(1 To rngUnqGroups.Cells.Count * lNumTopEntries, 1 To 3)
        i = 0

        For Each GroupCell In rngUnqGroups
            Set rngFound = .Find(GroupCell.Value, .Cells(.Cells.Count))
            k = 0
            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                For j = i + 1 To i + lNumTopEntries
                    If rngFound.Offset(j - i - 1).Value = GroupCell.Value Then
                        k = k + 1
                        aResults(j, 1) = rngFound.Offset(j - i - 1, -1).Value
                        aResults(j, 2) = rngFound.Offset(j - i - 1).Value
                        aResults(j, 3) = rngFound.Offset(j - i - 1, 1).Value
                    End If
                Next j
                i = i + k
            End If
        Next GroupCell
    End With

    'Output results'
    wsDest.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(aResults, 1), UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults

CleanExit:
    'Turn calculation, events, and screenupdating back on'
    With Application
        .Calculation = lCalc
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'There was an error, show the error'
        MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error: " & Err.Number
        Err.Clear
    End If

    'Put data back the way it was
    rngData.Value = aOriginal

End Sub
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Your highest three scores are **24, 24, and one of the two 18's**  Which of the two 18s do you want ??

Comment: After your data is sorted; set the variable `n` to three, or what ever number you want; then copy the top `n` rows starting from `A2` and bottom `n` rows starting at 2 rows above the last row e.g. `.Cells(lrow - 2, "A")` using the variable `lrow`; and paste to the worksheet/s as needed.

Comment: We will need your help by indicating what code you have so far, provided you're commenting «Similar questions have been answered here before, but the associated code and explanations do not guide me to the desired results».

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I would be selecting all the users earning with the 3 highest scores.

Comment: @GMalc That would not address the multiple users having the same scores. Moreover, I am trying to automate the process as this step has to be performed repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that such an Excel function already exists? The `Large(Range;n)` function returns the `n`th largest number out of your range, more explanation can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LARGE-function-3AF0AF19-1190-42BB-BB8B-01672EC00A64). If you want the smallest ones, you might use the `Small(Range;n)` function, described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-17DA8222-7C82-42B2-961B-14C45384DF07).

Comment: The `Large(Range;n)` function just returns the total number of users having the `n`th largest score.
I am looking to select the array of data for the top scoring users and then paste it on a separate sheet.